# В чем практический смысл FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, база-данных, foreign-key

В чем еще практический смысл использования FOREIGN KEY кроме того как это позволяет использовать конструкции ON DELETE и ON UPDATE

Даже JOIN'ы можно выполнять без FOREIGN KEY

Comment: Вы определитесь про какой ключ вы узнаете :)

Comment: @MichaelVaysman исправил, спасибо

Comment: INSERT/UPDATE с некорректным значением сделать не позволит

Comment: Используется для обеспечения т.н. `ссылочное целостности` или `referencial integrity`, которая гарантирует согласованность данных в таблицах, связанных этим `foreign key`

Comment: @Sergey а сама эта согласованность как помогает? Кроме того что всё по полочкам разложено

Comment: @JohnKent вы так говорите, будто бардак в базе это что-то хорошее)

Comment: @andreymal Возможно я не работал с крпуными базами, и на данный момент не могу понять все преимущества из-за этого.

Comment: @andreymal Некорректное значиние это когда, например, в колонку orders.user_id (PRIMARY KEY к users.id)  вставляется значения которого в users.id нет?

Comment: @JohnKent `что всё по полочкам разложено ` - это как бы само по себе естественное требование. Редко бывает иначе. И referencial integrity помогает достичь этого.

Comment: FOREIGN KEY не позволяет внести в данные такие изменения, при которых будут нарушены условия ссылочной целостности. Можно считать это "защитой от дурака".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да тут много чего можно сказать. Ключи - это удобная фича, а не надобность. Можно и без них обходиться, главное индексы только самим создать.

Из явных плюшек ключей как таковых:

1. `ON DELETE CASCADE`, когда при удалении родительской записи удалятся и все ссылающиеся на неё.
2. Защита от удаления записи, если кто-то на неё ссылается. К примеру, есть у вас таблицы `Склад` и `Предмет`. В `Предмет` есть внешняя ссылка на запись из `Склад`. Вы не можете удалить запись из `Склад`, пока на неё ссылается хоть один элемент из `Предмет`.
3. При вставке проверяется существование записей по внешним ключам.
4. и т.д.

В общем, по большей части они нужны для поддержания целостности базы данных.